# How to protect files on your website

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I will have clients upload pdf files with sensitive information. I'm planning on having the directory outside public_html. When a client want to download his/her file they will get a php link that will authenticate them. Is more I can do to protect such files?

Comment: This is a better question for http://security.stackexchange.com. @rwyland SSL only prevents MITM attacks.

Comment: @MattBall My point is still valid. You want people sniffing your sensitive pdfs? Or worse, your username/password when you authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Place the files outside docroot,
- make the temporary links (www.oink.com/abd73df10e92/whatever.pdf) expire,
- never direct link the files, use a php wrapper to readfile out the contents
- never use the stored filename,
- make sure the files have the least permissions
- if the files are really sensitive, provide them over only HTTPS

Comment: ... and consider encrypting them.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - you can implement "one-time-download" links: from a valid user session, you generate a link which, when accessed, does a server-side redirect to the file in question.

In your link handler you verify, via session cookies (or whatever mechanism) that the person visiting the link is authorized to access the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with that approach. You could require  a login password and make the only available download links the ones associated with the user's account. This would also be done with SSL of course.